# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Tags: json, parsing, syntax-error

I apologize for asking my question here.  I know nothing about JSON or syntax errors, but I'm hoping that someone might be able to give me some direction of where to find these files.

I am using Simple Membership registration for my website https://ChristianGays.com.  After a new member registers and they try to login for the first time, the page hangs and never loads.

Error console says: Invalid CSS property declaration at:;  smregistration:684
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'  parse - jquery.js4:16652

Under that is says Main Frame and if I click on that it says f1d6848b7518036 - page.php and below that fb_xdm_frame_https - fTmlQU3LxvB.js

Does this mean anything to anyone?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably because your request is returning an HTML instead of a JSON and when you try to parse it, the first char would be `<`, which is already invalid for a JSON string.

But it is really hard to be sure without you posting the HTTP response from server that you are trying to parse as a JSON or the code you are using to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error. The error was because of the URL not being encoded. The steps to make it work are

In the server side, I used JSON.stringify and encode like

`/login.html?userdetails="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(res))`

and in the client side, the details was obtained by

`JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params['userdetails']))`